# How can I make a bootable backup of Windows 7?

Tags: backup, bootable-media, windows-7

How can you make a bootable backup of the C: drive (bootable, or in safemode windows)?

I've got a problem with Windows and I can not boot Windows in normal mode!

Comment: Are you looking to make a backup of the entire drive? or are you looking to fix its boot problem?

Comment: If the drive or boot manager or booting files on windows is corrupted, then cloning the drive at this point will not fix the problem...

Comment: It might be better to tell us what your problem is, how it happened, and what you have tried so far, we may have better solutions for you. You can edit your original post and title to reflect this new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a clone of the hard disk image, consider downloading [Clonezilla Live CD](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php), burning it onto a disc and then creating an image of either your whole hard drive or the partitions. You will probably need an external harddrive to store the images.